# Is it safe to have two nodeJs version on the same machine in prod

Tags: node.js, nvm-windows

In production, I have a bunch of services running an older Node.js version. I would need to install a new one using the latest LTS version.

Is it safe to have both versions installed? The installer is asking for a path. This means that two versions can be installed, I imagine.

In development, nvm-windows is working fine, but it requires Internet access to install both versions. In production, there isn't any Internet access. What would be the best option here?

Comment: as far as I know, its pretty "safe", confusing? and painful to work with? a lot!, thats why this exists https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: yes painful, will avoid it and push to upgrade all service...